# Curling eWay from a terminal yields different response to curling from IIS

Tags: c#, iis, curl, eway

I am able to curl ewayAPI following examples for "transparent redirect" in their API.

However converting the exact same curl request into C# code I get the following error codes: V6011 and V6047

I have checked and rechecked and even used wireshark to make sure that what I am sending through C# has the same package content as what I am sending through terminal.

I think there is some encoding issue or setting in IIS on my dev box that is distorting the curl request to eway which doesn't happen in terminal.

Does anyone know if there is a setting I have to select in IIS to ensure the curl requests get through?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it turns out that eway is very touchy about the request headers.

```
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.Parameters.Clear();
        request.AddParameter("application/json", strJSONContent, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Adding the header as well as the content type for "application/json" solved it using restsharp.

Comment: There is also an [eWAY NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/eWAY.Rapid/) package which deals with those details if you prefer